# I want to read each element and depth position of that element from an array

Tags: javascript

I want to know each element depth position in array.

for example input:  `[1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, 8, [9, 10]];`
and output

```
each_element  position 
1              0
2              0
3              1
4              1
5              2
6              2
7              0
8              0
9              1
10             1
```

I wrote a function but it return wrong. any one can do solve this problem.

my code is bellow please let me know what's is wrong with my code.

```js
function rec(arr, dept = 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] == 'object') {
      dept = dept + 1;
      rec(arr[i], dept);
    } else {
      console.log(arr[i], dept);
    }
  }
}

let arr = [1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, 8, [9, 10]];
rec(arr)
```

Comment: Why `depth` of `9 and 10` is `0`, shouldn't be `1`?

Comment: Also 2 isn't at position 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable to other, you are modifying same variable.

```js
    function rec(arr,dept=0){
        
        for(var i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
        
            if(typeof arr[i] == 'object'){
                
                dept2 =  dept+1;            
                rec(arr[i],dept2);
            }else{
               
                console.log(arr[i],dept);
                
            }        
        }
    }
    let arr = [1,2,[3],[4,[5,6]],7,8,[9,10]];
    rec(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method and create recursive function that returns an object as a result.

```js
let arr =  [1, 2, [3], [4, [5, 6]], 7, 8, [9, 10]];

function rec(data, lvl = 0) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(e)) r[e] = lvl;
    else Object.assign(r, rec(e, lvl + 1))
    return r;
  }, {})
}

console.log(rec(arr))
```